# Jquery Ui datepicker format of date alone needs to be changed but when i try to change it both value and placeholder are changing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a juquery ui based datepicker in my  design in that i need the value to be like this format 
day_month_year

For that i have added jquery script that change value perfetly but same time it was showing front end also like the same. day_month_year

I need front end to be shown like this day/month/year

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd_mm_yy' }).val();
  } );
   $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd_mm_yy' }).val();
  } );
   $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe this will help you:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd_mm_yy",
    altField: "#alternate",
    altFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Date 1: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
<br /> Date 2: <input type="text" id="alternate" />
```

Hope it helps.